# MySql INNER JOIN, ERROR #1066

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 database.

**grameenphone_bill** » **Table**: tbl_admin--> cp_id

**banglalink_bill** »**Table**: tbl_billing_response-> cpid

**robi_bill** »**Table**: tbl_billing_response-> cpid

All the three db's table's  have two fields common i.e ChargedAmount and cpid.
The login is done through **grameenphone_bill** » **Table**: tbl_admin.

Now, i want to calculate the revenue i.e ChargedAmount by using cpid

I have written a query but getting error 
**#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tbl_admin'**

here's the query i wrote.

```
SELECT grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin.cp_id,
       grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin.cp_name,
       banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid,
       robi_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid,
       grameenphone_bill.tbl_billing_response.ChargedAmount,
       banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response.ChargedAmount,
       robi_bill.tbl_billing_response.ChargedAmount
FROM grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin
INNER JOIN grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin ON grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin.cp_id=banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid
INNER JOIN banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response ON banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid=robi_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid
```

Please tell me, where i'm going wrong.
Thanks!!

Comment: Just use alias name for joining your problem will resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `join` is incorrect - you don't need to join `tbl_admin`, it's already in your `from` clause:

```
SELECT     grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin.cp_id,
           grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin.cp_name,
           banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid,
           robi_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid,
           grameenphone_bill.tbl_billing_response.ChargedAmount,
           banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response.ChargedAmount,
           robi_bill.tbl_billing_response.ChargedAmount
FROM       grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin
INNER JOIN banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response ON 
           grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin.cp_id = 
           banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid
INNER JOIN robi_bill.tbl_billing_response ON 
           banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid = 
           robi_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid
```

Comment: Getting error:  #1054 - Unknown column 'robi_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid' in 'field list'

Comment: arg, dropped a line there... fixed - see my latest edit

Answer (score 0):

You are joining grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin with grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin itself. I think it should have been robi_bill.tbl_billing_response instead.

```
SELECT grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin.cp_id,
       grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin.cp_name,
       banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid,
       robi_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid,
       grameenphone_bill.tbl_billing_response.ChargedAmount,
       banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response.ChargedAmount,
       robi_bill.tbl_billing_response.ChargedAmount
FROM grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin
INNER JOIN banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response ON grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin.cp_id=banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid
INNER JOIN robi_bill.tbl_billing_response ON banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid=robi_bill.tbl_billing_response.cpid
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you are selecting one table two times in one select you should give an alias to at least one of it :

```
SELECT gta.cp_id,
       gta.cp_name,
       ba.cpid,
       rb.cpid,
       gta.ChargedAmount,
       ba.ChargedAmount,
       rb.ChargedAmount
FROM grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin gta
INNER JOIN banglalink_bill.tbl_billing_response ba ON gta.cp_id=ba.cpid
INNER JOIN robi_bill.tbl_billing_response rb ON ba.cpid=rb.cpid
```

I hope your problem will resolve.